# java.lang.module.FindException: Module JavaFXApp not found

Tags: javafx

I want to make a Desktop Application with JavaFX.
I am using JDK - 20 and JavaFX 21-0-1.

[image: file]

I am positive that I've placed the module-info file in the right place.

[image: info]

the VM option is also correct according to the syntax.

[image: error]

still I am facing the same error again and again.

Comment: Is your module `JavaFXApp`?  Edit the question, provide the text of the `module-info.java` file as text, formatted as code.

Comment: Follow one of the flows at https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/

Answer (score 1):

**Example working JavaFX application with gradle**
https://github.com/davidweber411/JavaFxAppGradleNonModular

**Example working JavaFX application with maven**
https://github.com/davidweber411/JavaFxAppMavenNonModular

**Note:**

These are non modular applications. You don't need a module.info class. You can just download, edit and run them.

To that, you can check out the code and look how it is done.

Answer (score 1):

The highlighting in your module-info by the IDE probably indicates that the IDE cannot find the required JavaFX dependencies, likely making the module definition invalid.  Perhaps additionally, you may be trying to run your application on the classpath rather than the module path (hence the module not found error).

It is a maven project (has a `.mvn` directory), but has no `pom.xml` file -> that is strange, (maybe one was generated for the new project and deleted).

The `pom.xml` defines the dependencies needed by the application.  Usually, for a modular JavaFX project such as you have, the `pom.xml` will include the dependencies. Once Maven is providing the JavaFX dependencies, you don't need to (and should not) set the "VM option" for JavaFX (at least for execution within the context of the Idea IDE).

As you are using Idea, if you follow their [instructions for creating a new JavaFX project](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javafx.html), you should be able to create a new project with ease.  It will correctly configure required JavaFX dependencies and a working `module-info.java`, allowing you to build and run your application within the IDE.

There are other methods for creating new JavaFX projects (as noted in other comments or answers here), but, for your environment, following the IDE instructions is likely the easiest.  Once you get a new project to work, I'd advise slowly copying the code from your existing project, building and executing with each step to ensure that it continues to work.